# How to sort immutable slice in Rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose that I have the following code snippet:

```rust
fn foo(xs: &[i32]) {
    xs.sort(); // doesn't work since not mut
    // computation on xs
}
```

This function takes in an unsorted immutable slice but I need it to be sorted for computations later on in the function. I also cannot change the function signature. Is there a way to sort `xs` out of place or a way to convert xs into a mutable slice?

I've tried cloning and mapping but it seems that the problem is with the type of `xs`.

Comment: Clone it first then sort it?

Comment: You can't mutate immutable slice, so even if you'll clone it and sort clone, you'll have to return it, but it would need a change in function signature.
I don't believe that this is a case, but you might want to look for *unsafe* feature in Rust, to overpass it.

Comment: If you can change function signature to let's say: fn foo(xs: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32>,
then you can try something like that:
{
    let mut clone = vec![0; xs.len()];
    clone.clone_from_slice(xs);
    clone.sort();
    clone
}

Comment: @Miokloń: You're assuming that the caller needs to have access to the sorted slice; I had instead understood that `foo` will perform some computation with the sorted slice, and then discard it.

Comment: @eggyal: yeah, it might be, then cloning from slice serves (which indeed is not needed, to_vec() works too)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the data is immutable, you have to make a mutable copy of it first. You do not statically know the size of the slice parameter, so you need to use a `Vec` (instead of an array) to copy into. Then you can sort that `Vec` and use it normally in the rest of your function:

```rust
fn foo(xs: &[i32]) {
    let mut xs = xs.to_vec();
    xs.sort();
    // computation on xs
}
```

Comment: "*You do not statically know the size of the slice parameter*": that has nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: @hellow, if you did know the size statically, then you could allocate an array (instead of a Vec) of that size.

Comment: Again, the size of the slice has nothing to do with sorting. It's not possible to sort an immutable slice in rust. You have to have mutable access to the underlying data. You do that by copying the slice into a `Vec`, which is fine. But it does not have anything to do with the size.

Comment: @hellow, I think we are talking past each other a bit. Yes, you have to copy the data first because it is immutable. But it could be copied into an array or into a Vec. This last choice depends on whether you know the size of the data statically.